# How R extracts function definitions in a dynamic library

Tags: c, r

When there is a function defined in `source.c` like

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

SEXP myfunc (SEXP n1, SEXP n2){
    SEXP mysum_sexp;
    PROTECT(mysum_sexp = NEW_NUMERIC(1));
    PROTECT(n1);
    PROTECT(n2);
    NUMERIC_POINTER(mysum_sexp)[0] = NUMERIC_POINTER(n1)[0] 
                                   + NUMERIC_POINTER(n2)[0];
    UNPROTECT(3);
    return(mysum_sexp);
}
```

and the `source.c` file is compiled using

```
R CMD SHLIB source.c
```

a dynamic (shared) library is created with default name `source.so`. After the compiling process, when we type in `R`

```
> dyn.load("source.so")
```

the function in the compiled code can be called using as

```
> .Call("myfunc", 4, 7)
```

and the result is `11` as expected. How `R` passes the arguments to the foreign function without knowing the definition of the function? Is the calling process blank or does `R` follow standard definitions with n arguments in type of `SEXP` for `n = 1, 2, ..., n1`?

I know using the `.Call` interface without `Rcpp` is old fashioned but I want to learn the mechanism behind it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to know "how" R passes the arguments? Like how values are put into memory or something? By defintion of the function, do you mean just the signature of the function, or all the code inside as well? I'm not sure what type of answer you are looking for. Those two arguments are passed into the parameters of the function you are calling. Do you want to go into how programming languages are compiled into machine code? I'm just not sure what would be helpful to you.

Comment: @MrFlick Suppose you write a simple C program that loads a shared library and calls an unknown function with unknown number of arguments which are typed by the user in runtime. How would you implement this? This is the summary of my question.

Comment: So the real question isn't R related at all? It would be nice to have a minimal example of such a scenario then that just involves C. The code that R runs when you call `.Call` is [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/dotcode.c#L1222)

Comment: @MrFlick when you replace the "simple C program" with "R", the summary is exactly related to R because I don't know whether this process can be implemented in many ways and if yes, I want to learn how R handles this. Thank you for the link, I will have a look.

Comment: There is no Rcpp content here.  You seem to be asking basic R/C questions,  Ok if I remove the Rcpp tag?

Comment: @MrFlick it seems R holds the definitions in R_RegisteredNativeSymbol and extracts the arguments using resolveNativeRoutine(). A deep source code reading may help to answer my question. Maybe somebody makes a clean explaination. Thank you!

Comment: @MrFlick thank you, the switch-case part of the code explains my question. R follows a standard definition with varying number of arguments in type of SEXP. Thank you again.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to [MrFlick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2372064/mrflick), he sent me the link of the source of [dotcode.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/5a156a0865362bb8381dcd69ac335f5174a4f60c/src/main/dotcode.c#L1222) and this peace of code explains my question:

```
switch (nargs) {
case 0:
  retval = (SEXP)ofun();
  break;
case 1:
  retval = (SEXP)fun(cargs[0]);
  break;
case 2:
  retval = (SEXP)fun(cargs[0], cargs[1]);
  break;
case 3:
  retval = (SEXP)fun(cargs[0], cargs[1], cargs[2]);
  break;
case 4:
  retval = (SEXP)fun(cargs[0], cargs[1], cargs[2], cargs[3]);
  break;
case 5:
  .
  .
  .
case 65:
.
.
default:
}
```

It seems `R` looks at the number of arguments and follows a standard definition which takes several numbers (or none) of SEXP arguments at runtime. The maximum number of arguments allowed is `65`. It is known that all of the functions return a SEXP. Situations are hand coded. That proves that the foreign function calling is blank, in other words, number of entered arguments directly determines the function definition.